# Rand5() to Rand7()

Tags: code-challenge, math, random

You are provided with a function Rand5(). This function returns perfectly random (equal distribution) integers between 1 and 5.

Provide the function Rand7(), which uses Rand5() to produce perfectly random integers between 1 and 7.

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137783/365102)

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: 1 and 5 inclusive? i.e. from the set {1,2,3,4,5} ?

Comment: What criteria determines a single winner?

Comment: That moment when you realize this is actually an old question.

Comment: @nyuszika7h That moment when a question is put on hold after nearly 4 years and the OP hasn't been on PPCG since May. :P

Answer (score 12):

Java - 61 chars

```
int rand7(){int s=0,c=7;while(c-->0)s+=rand5();return s%7+1;}
```

Test driver for validation:

```
class Rand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[7];
        // get a lot of numbers
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) nums[rand7()-1]++;
        // print the results
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) System.out.println((i+1) + ": " + nums[i]);
    }

    // just for rand5()
    static java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();

    static int rand5() {
        return r.nextInt(5)+1; // Random.nextInt(n) returns 0..n-1, so add 1
    }

    static int rand7(){int s=0,c=7;while(c-->0)s+=rand5();return s%7+1;}

}
```

Results

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Rand
1: 1429828
2: 1429347
3: 1428328
4: 1426486
5: 1426784
6: 1429853
7: 1429374

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>
```

Comment: Extra points for the "goes to operator"

Comment: shave a char?  int rand7(){for(int s=0,c=7;c-->0;s+=rand5());return s%7+1;}

Comment: This answer is not correct: the probabilities of this function returning the values from 1 to 7 are 0.1430656, 0.1430016, 0.1428224, 0.1426432, 0.1426432, 0.1428224 and 0.1430016 respectively. Yes, the difference between the minimum and maximum probabilities is less that 0.0005, but still, the question specified "perfectly random integers".

Comment: @ilmari You're right - I just ran a test and it seems the distribution isn't even... let me think on that...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I guess I know the solution. :)

Comment: @glowcoder: Since @Ilmari does not respond any more: I guess he forgot to use a perfectly random `Rand5 ()` as input, and therefore earned not perfect Rand7 as output.

Comment: @userunknown That's not the case. The case is that the addition used is less likely to wind up in the middle than the edge cases. This is evidenced by my output too, but it's very subtle!

Comment: @userunknown: Yes, the probabilities I posted are actually not approximations, they exact (0.1430656 = 11177 / 78125, etc.) assuming a perfectly random `rand5`. I computed them in Maple using simple matrix algebra, but you can do it with pencil and paper in a few minutes if you want. Anyway, it turns out Omar already posted the same figures (sans normalizing factor) in a comment to [another answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2368/3191) a couple of days earlier. (Also ps., you can only @notify one user per comment, although the post's author is notified always in any case.)

Answer (score 8):

### Perl - 47 (was 52) chars

```
sub rand7{($x=5*&rand5+&rand5-3)<24?int($x/3):&rand7}
```

Plus I get to use the ternary operator AND recursion. Best... day... ever!

OK, 47 chars if you use mod instead of div:

```
sub rand7{($x=5*&rand5+&rand5)<27?$x%7+1:&rand7}
```

Comment: So close... replace the 30 with 27 (= 6 + 21) and you'll get a perfectly uniform distribution.  Oh, and you can drop the last two `&` signs to get it down to 46 chars (including the space, which puts your current version at 48).

Answer (score 7):

In Python:

```
def Rand7():
  while True:
    x = (Rand5() - 1) * 5 + (Rand5() - 1)
    if x < 21: return x/3 + 1
```

Comment: in Python 3.X, use `return x//3 + 1`

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript, 42

```
Rand7=f=_=>(x=Rand5()+Rand5()*5-5)>7?f():x
```

Bonus ES5 thing:

```
Rand7=eval.bind(0,'for(;x=Rand5()+Rand5()*5-5,x>7;);x')
```

Answer (score 7):

Ruby - 54 chars (based on Dan McGrath solution, using loop)

```
def rand7;x=8;while x>7 do x=rand5+5*rand5-5 end;x;end
```

Ruby - 45 chars (same solution, using recursion)

```
def rand7;x=rand5+5*rand5-5;x>7 ?rand7: x;end
```

Comment: Can be shortened by 1 char by using `(x=rand5+5*rand5-5)>7?`.

Answer (score 5):

In Common Lisp 70 characters:

```
(defun rand7()(let((n(-(+(rand5)(* 5(rand5)))5)))(if(> n 7)(rand7)n)))
```

The parenthesis take up more space than I would like.

Comment: Nice.  You can squeeze out two more characters by making n a global variable: `(defun rand7()(setq n(-(+(rand5)(* 5(rand5)))5))(if(> n 7)(rand7)n))`

Comment: Even better: `(defun rand7()(if(>(setq n(-(+(rand5)(* 5(rand5)))5))7)(rand7)n))`

Answer (score 4):

In c/c++ using [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)

```
int rand7(){int x=8;while(x>7)x=rand5()+5*rand5()-5;return x;}
```

62 characters.

Comment: @barrycarter: The condition is `while(x>7)`, so that would only be satisfied by numbers in the valid range.

Comment: My bad. Deleted my dumb comment.

Comment: @barry And then you left another one. ;)

Comment: It took me a few minutes to realize how the math here produces a uniformly random distribution which can be used for rejection sampling.

Answer (score 4):

Translation to PHP, from the answer posted ny Dan McGrath.

```
function Rand7(){$x=8;while($x>7)$x=rand5()+5*rand5()-5;return $x;}
```

67 characters.

Comment: Shouldn't this be prefixed by the word "function" (and a space)?

Comment: Yeah... and now it's 67 characters...

Answer (score 4):

## R, 34 characters

In R (a language built for statistical computation), a deliberately cheaterish solution:

```
# Construct a Rand5 function
Rand5 <- function() sample(seq(5),1)
# And the golf
Rand7=function(r=Rand5())sample(1:(r/r+6),1)
# Or (same character count)
Rand7=function(r=Rand5())sample.int(r/r+6,1)
# Or even shorter(thanks to @Spacedman)
Rand7=function()sample(7)[Rand5()]
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation of arguments, I eliminated the semicolon and braces.

Output over 10^6 replicates:

```
> test <- replicate(10^6,Rand7())
> table(test)
test
     1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
142987 142547 143133 142719 142897 142869 142848 

library(ggplot2)
qplot(test)
```

[image: histogram of results]

Comment: If you're going to be cheaterish, you may as well be the best cheater you can be: `Rand7=function(){r=Rand5();sample(7)[r]}`

Comment: If you are going to do that, why bother with the intermediate storage? `Rand7=function(){sample(7)[Rand5()]}`

Comment: @BrianDiggs Path-dependency in action.... :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Java (or C/C++ I suppose)

- using generation formula by Alexandru, in 65 characters:

  ```
  int rand7(){int x=rand5()*5+rand5()-6;return x>20?rand7():x/3+1;}
  ```
- using generation formula by Dan McGrath, in 60 characters

  ```
  int rand7(){int x=rand5()+5*rand5()-5;return x>7?rand7():x;}
  ```

Answer (score 3):

### C++

```
int Rand4()
{
    int r = Rand5();
    return r > 4 ? Rand4() : r;
}

inline int Rand8()
{    
    return (Rand4() - 1) << 2 + Rand4();
}

int Rand7()
{
    int r = Rand8();
    return r > 7 ? Rand7() : r;
}
```

---

### C++ (109)

#### Golfed

```
int Rand4(){int r=Rand5();return r>4?Rand4():r;}int Rand7(){int r=Rand4()-1<<2+Rand4();return r>7?Rand7():r;}
```

Comment: I don't really think you can call that a "one liner" because semicolons define a line of code in C++.

Comment: @Peter Oh well, it doesn't even require one-liners anymore.

Comment: It returned a number from 1 to 8.

Answer (score 3):

### scala,  <strike>47, 40</strike> 59 chars:

```
def rand7:Int={val r=5*(rand5-1)+rand5
if(r<8)r else rand7}
```

with 2 inputs from rand5:

```
\ 1 2 3 4 5 
1 1 2 3 4 5  
2 6 7 8 ..
3 11 ..
4 ..
5
```

I multiply the first-1 by 5, and add the second. Most results are ignored, and lead to a new calculation. The result should be an equal distribution of values from 1-25, from which I only pick the first 7 ones. I could accept the first 21 with building a modulo, but this would lead to longer code.

historic code which failed, but not very obviously. Thanks to Ilmari Karonen for pointing it out:

```
def rand7=(1 to 7).map(_=>rand5).sum%7+1
```

Thanks to Yoshiteru Takeshita, for this scala-2.8.0-approach which made 'sum' so easy. My solution before:

```
def rand7=((0/:(1 to 7))((a,_)=>a+rand5-1))%7+1
```

rand5:

```
val rnd = util.Random 
def rand5 = rnd.nextInt (5) + 1
```

Comment: User [Yoshiteru Takeshita](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2129/yoshiteru-takeshita) proposed a reduction to 40 chars for Scala 2.8.0 or later as `def rand7=(1 to 7).map(_=>rand5).sum%7+1`

Comment: This solution is also not correct, see the comments to [glowcoder's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2244/3191).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: You're right - I reworked my solution.

Answer (score 3):

### С++

```
int Rand7()
{
    int r = Rand5();
    int n = 5;
    do {
        r = (r - 1) * 5 + Rand5();
        int m = n * 5 / 7 * 7;
        if (r <= m) {
            return r % 7 + 1;
        }
        r -= m;
        n = n * 5 - m;
    } while (1);
}
```

Numbers distribution (1000000 integers):

```
142935 142751 142652 143299 142969 142691 142703
```

Average number of calls to Rand5() per every generated integer is about 2.2 (2 to 10+).

```
1 2      3      4     5    6   7 8  9 10
0 840180 112222 44433 2212 886 0 60 6 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Translation to Javascript, from the answer posted by Dan McGrath.

```
function Rand7(){x=8;while(x>7)x=rand5()+5*rand5()-5;return x}
```

**62 chars**

Comment: `function Rand7(){for(x=8;x>7;x=rand5()+5*rand5()-5);return x}` is little shorter :P

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <strike>56</strike> 37 chars

Another solution that may be wrong, in Python:

```
rand7 = lambda: sum(rand5() for i in range(7)) % 7 + 1
```

This seems to be too simple, but when I try:

```
counter = [0] * 7
for i in range(100000):
     counter[rand7()] += 1
```

I get a reasonably even distribution (all between 14000 and 14500).

Okay, now as somebody voted for this post: Is this solution indeed correct? I more posted this here to make people criticize it. Well, if it is correct, my golfed version would be:

```
rand7=lambda:eval("+rand5()"*7)%7+1
```

which comes out to 37 chars.

Comment: Your solution is not correct: you base your decision on 7 rolls of a fair 5-sided die, which means there are 5^7 (5 to the 7th power) equiprobable outcomes. Since this is not a multiple of 7, you cannot return 7 equiprobable results. I don't think there's an easy formula for what you return; you can brute-force the computation or work it out by hand on smaller numbers (flip 3 coins (H=1, T=2) and sum the results).

Comment: Wow, the distribution you generate, though not uniform, is remarkably close: the exact proportion of the probabilities of each number is {1: 11177, 2: 11172, 3: 11158, 4: 11144, 5: 11144, 6: 11158, 7: 11172}

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 85

```
function Rand7(){for(x=0,i=1;i<8;x^=i*((k=Rand5())%2),i*=1+(k<5));return x?x:Rand7()}
```

I know there's shorter answer, but I wanted to show the [test](http://jsfiddle.net/JIminP/KPLkT/) of this puzzle. It turns out that only Clyde Lobo's answer using Dan McGrath's rejection sampling is correct (between JS answers).

Answer (score 2):

Java, 65 chars:

```
int rand7(){int r;do{r=rand5()+5*rand5()-5;}while(r>7);return r;}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java - 66 chars

```java
int rand7(){int s;while((s=rand5()*5+rand5())<10);return(s%7+1);}
```

Longer than previous routine, but I think this one returns uniformly distributed numbers in less time.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure - 58 chars

```
(defn rand7[](#(if(<% 8)%(rand7))(+(rand5)(*(rand5)5)-5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 70 chars

```
def rand7():
 while True:
  n=5*(rand5()-1)+(rand5()-1)
  if n<21:return n%7+1
```

but completely correct based on the reasoning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7).

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 43 chars, iterative rejection sampling

```
sub rand7{1while($_=5*&rand5-rand5)>6;$_+1}
```

This gives a warning about `Ambiguous use of -rand5 resolved as -&rand5()`, but works correctly.  Prepending an `&` also to the second `rand5` call fixes it at the cost of one stroke.  (Conversely, the other `&` can also be removed *if* `rand5` has been defined with a `()` prototype.)

Ps. The following 46-char version is about three times faster:

```
sub rand7{1while($_=5*&rand5-rand5)>20;$_%7+1}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PostScript (46)**

This uses binary token encoding, therefore, here is a hexdump:

```
00000000  2f 72 61 6e 64 37 7b 38  7b 92 38 37 92 61 7b 92  |/rand7{8{.87.a{.|
00000010  40 7d 69 66 92 75 32 7b  72 61 6e 64 35 7d 92 83  |@}if.u2{rand5}..|
00000020  35 92 6c 92 01 35 92 a9  7d 92 65 7d 92 33        |5.l..5..}.e}.3|
0000002e
```

To try it out, you can also [download it](http://www.mediafire.com/?ceas14shso7e97x).

Here is the ungolfed and commented code, together with testing code.

```
% This is the actual rand7 procedure.
/rand7{
  8{                      % potentialResult
    % only if the random number is less than or equal to 7, we're done
    dup 7 le{             % result
      exit                % result
    }if                   % potentialResult
    pop                   % -/-
    2{rand5}repeat        % randomNumber1 randomNumber2
    5 mul add 5 sub       % randomNumber1 + 5*randomNumber2 - 5 = potentialResult
  }loop
}def

%Now, some testing code.

% For testing, we use the built-in rand operator; 
% Doesn't really give a 100% even distribution as it returns numbers
% from 0 to 2^31-1, which is of course not divisible by 5.
/rand5 {
  rand 5 mod 1 add
}def

% For testing, we initialize a dict that counts the number of times any number
% has been returned. Of course, we start the count at 0 for every number.
<<1 1 7{0}for>>begin

% Now we're calling the function quite a number of times 
% and increment the counters accordingly.
1000000 {
  rand7 dup load 1 add def
}repeat

% Print the results
currentdict{
  2 array astore ==
}forall
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i++; i<7)
    if (((rand(5) + rand(5)) % 2) //check if odd
        result += 1;

return result + 1;
```

Comment: This won't give a uniform distribution. Look at the distribution of rand(5)+rand(5) over 10000 iterations to see why

Comment: result can be any number from 1 to 8 in your code...

Comment: Plus, as gnibbler said, the distribution is not uniform: (rand(5)+rand(5))%2 is biased towards 0, it produces 0 13 times for every 12 times it produces 1; i.e., the probabilities are proportional to {0: 13, 1: 12}. With that notation, the probalities for your function are proportional to {1: 62748517, 2 : 405451956, 3: 1122790032, 4: 1727369280, 5: 1594494720, 6: 883104768, 7: 271724544, 8: 35831808} (quite heavily skewed towards larger numbers). Or, fixing the loop to run 6 times, {1: 4826809, 2: 26733096, 3: 61691760, 4: 75928320, 5: 52565760, 6: 19408896, 7: 2985984}

Answer (score 0):

## R (30 characters)

Define rand7:

```
rand7=function(n)sample(7,n,T)
```

Because R was written with statistical analysis in mind, this task is trivial, and I use the built-in function `sample` with replacement set to TRUE.

Sample output:

```
> rand7(20)
 [1] 4 3 6 1 2 4 3 2 3 2 5 1 4 6 4 2 4 6 6 1
> rand7(20)
 [1] 1 2 5 2 6 4 6 1 7 1 1 3 7 6 4 7 4 2 1 2
> rand7(20)
 [1] 6 7 1 3 3 1 5 4 3 4 2 1 5 4 4 4 7 7 1 5
```

Comment: It does say you have to use Rand5. Doesn't say how, but you have to use it...

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I explicitly ignored it. That is use by non-reference.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy

```
rand7={if(b==null)b=rand5();(b=(rand5()+b)%7+1)}
```

example distribution over 35,000 iterations:

```
[1:5030, 2:4909, 3:5017, 4:4942, 5:5118, 6:4956, 7:5028]
```

Is it bad that it's stateful?

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 30

```
Rand7=Rand5[]~Sum~{7}~Mod~7+1&
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int Rand7()
{
    return Rand5()+ Rand5()/2;
}
```

Comment: Whatever language that is, does its `/` operator do integer math? What happens to your results if it does decimal, floating-point, or integer math?

Comment: Assuming integer division, this function has the following distribution: `[2/25, 4/25, 5/25, 5/25, 5/25, 3/25, 1/25]`. Not exactly uniform.

Comment: primo is right. adding random numbers is generally going to skew the probabilities toward the middle values.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby (43 bytes)

```
def rand7;(0..7).reduce{|i|i+rand5}%7+1;end
```

cemper93's solution ported to Ruby is three bytes shorter ;) (34 bytes)

```
def rand7;eval("+rand5"*7)%7+1;end
```

Answer (score -1):

### Java - 54

```java
int m=0;int rand7(){return(m=m*5&-1>>>1|rand5())%7+1;}
```

Distribution test:
`[1000915, 999689, 999169, 998227, 1001653, 1000419, 999928]`

Algorithm:

- Keep a global variable
- multiply by 5, so there get 5 places free at the least significant end
- Truncate the sign bit to make it positive (not necessary if unsigned numbers were supported)
- Modulo 7 is the answer

> The numbers are not mutually uncorrelated anymore, but individually perfectly random.

Answer (score -2):

**C/C++ code** the core code has one line only!

```
static unsigned int gi = 0;

int rand7()
{
    return (((rand() % 5 + 1) + (gi++ % 7)) % 7) + 1;
}

//call this seed before rand7
//maybe it's not best seed, if yo have any good idea tell me please
//and thanks JiminP again, he remind me to do this
void srand7()
{
    int i, n = time(0);
    for (i = 0; i < n % 7; i++)
        rand7();
}
```

The srand7() is the seed of rand7, must call this function before rand7, just like call srand before rand in C.

This is a very good one, because it call rand() only one time, and no loop thing, no expends extra memories.

Let me explain it: consider a integer array with size of 5:

```
1st get one number from 1 2 3 4 5 by rand5
2nd get one number from 2 3 4 5 6
3rd get one number from 3 4 5 6 7
4th get one number from 4 5 6 7 1
5th get one number from 5 6 7 1 2
5th get one number from 6 7 1 2 3
7th get one number from 7 1 2 3 4
```

So we got the TABLE, each one of 1-7 appears 5 times in it, and has all 35 numbers, so the probability of each number is 5/35=1/7. And next time,

```
8th get one number from 1 2 3 4 5
9th get one number from 2 3 4 5 6
......
```

After enough times, we can get the uniform distribution of 1-7.

So, we can allocate a array to restore the five elements of 1-7 by loop-left-shift, and get one number from array each time by rand5. Instead, we can generate the all seven arrays before, and using them circularly. The code is simple also, has many short codes can do this.

But, we can using the properties of % operation, so the table 1-7 rows is equivalent with (rand5 + i) % 7, that is :
a = rand() % 5 + 1 is rand5 in C language,
b = gi++ % 7 generates all permutations in table above, and 0 - 6 replace 1 - 7
c = (a + b) % 7 + 1, generates 1 - 7 uniformly.
Finally, we got this code:

```
(((rand() % 5 + 1) + (gi++ % 7)) % 7) + 1
```

But, we can not get 6 and 7 at first call, so we need a seed, some like srand for rand in C/C++, to disarrange the permutation for first formal call.

Here is the full code to testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static unsigned int gi = 0;

//a = rand() % 5 + 1 is rand5 in C language,
//b = gi++ % 7 generates all permutations,
//c = (a + b) % 7 + 1, generates 1 - 7 uniformly.
//Dont forget call srand7 before rand7
int rand7()
{
   return (((rand() % 5 + 1) + (gi++ % 7)) % 7) + 1;
}

//call this seed before rand7
//maybe it's not best seed, if yo have any good idea tell me please
//and thanks JiminP again, he remind me to do this
void srand7()
{
    int i, n = time(0);
    for (i = 0; i < n % 7; i++)
        rand7();
}

void main(void)
{
    unsigned int result[10] = {0};
    int k;

    srand((unsigned int)time(0)); //initialize the seed for rand
    srand7() //initialize the rand7

    for (k = 0; k < 100000; k++)
        result[rand7() - 1]++;

    for (k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        printf("%d : %.05f\n", k + 1, (float)result[k]/100000);
}
```

Comment: It 'passes' the 'test', but that doesn't mean this is a good random function. Can I get `6` or `7` by calling it *once*?

Comment: But there's good kinds and bad kinds of approximation. And this code is bad - because it **does not** gives uniform distribution when called only once. If one wrote something like `int main(){if(rand7()==6) printf("Hello, world!");}`, approximation using loop will print 'Hello, world!' 1 in 7 times, but your code doesn't.

Comment: thank you @JiminP! you are right for 6,7 at first time. i need a seed to disarrange before call rand7, the seed just like the srand in C/C++. i fixed my code, and thank you again!!!

Comment: hm....the srand10 does not work, the last 3 numbers can not get at 10, 20, 30 ...positions. sorry @JiminP, but how to modify it? i think this is hopeful way.

Comment: Different calls to this function are not independent of each other. The spec here doesn't require this, but that is typically expecetd of random number generators. Otherwise, you could say, return a random uniform number the first time and in future calls  just return (previous+1)%7...

Answer (score -3):

#### JavaScript (53 characters):

```
function Rand7(){return Math.abs(Rand5()-3)+Rand5()}
```

JSFiddle Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4DXN6/)

Same algorithm on **PHP (49 characters):**

```
function Rand7(){return abs(Rand5()-3)+Rand5();}
```

Comment: The resulting distribution is not uniform. For instance the chance of pulling a seven is `P(7) = 0.4 * 0.2 = 0.08 != 1/7`.